# Ambient music for online sessions

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, tools, gm-preparation, music, fantasy-grounds

I'm DMing a Forgotten Realms campaign online, and wanted to ask how people play music so everyone can hear. I'm looking for a site or application, possibly that I could integrate with Fantasy Grounds, that would let me choose a song from different folders and broadcast to players at the same time.

Comment: I am assuming that your campaigns aren't in person (or you would just use a stereo).  If so what medium are you using to run the campaign?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really an IT question, not an RPG question.

Comment: I won't vote to close; I feel like this is on-topic because valid answers could also be virtual tabletop related and this is a question that someone might come here to look for an answer to...

Comment: I edited your post with some grammar corrections and edited the question toward being on-topic; if you don't like what I've done you can choose to 'roll back' the changes or re-update them yourself. I also added more applicable [tags]

Comment: Keeping it open is fine, as long as the question is clearly about *how* to play music so that everyone can hear. If the question is looking for sources of music or the technical end of integrating music (i.e. what programs or computer setups are required), then it is OT as a "shopping question".

Comment: at the moment it is definitely a shopping question and needs to be reworded or closed

Answer (score 2):

### I would go with [TableTop Audio](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjcoLWSrqXWAhUCkJAKHd8uDVkQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftabletopaudio.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFAwsHT2kOQPulofyk-JG5zjGfE4A).

Great background music, with lots of scenarios and different worlds, and the SoundPad system is just awesome, with specific themes and loads of customization. You can mix background effects like rain, sword hits, monster noises and so many others.

Oh, and you can **broadcast it** to friends too. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Discord, it has a feature to this in the proper voice chat.